# Using ternary operator to output a string containing whitespace in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use a ternary operator in Razor, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes), but what I want to output contains whitespace. This code

```
@(selectedGoal == null ? "" : "value=" + selectedGoal.Name)
```

should produce

```
value="Goal 3"
```

as the value of selectedGoal.Name is "Goal 3". Instead, I get

```
value="Goal" 3
```

which is no good. I've tried a bunch of different combinations of escaped quotes, @ symbols and no @ symbols, and I just can't get this to work, i.e.

```
@(selectedGoal == null ? "" : "value=" + "selectedGoal.Name")
@(selectedGoal == null ? "" : "value=@selectedGoal.Name")
```

and then I just get something like

```
value="selectedGoal.Name"
```

Anyone know how this should be done?

Comment: Nothing you are showing would produce those results.  Clearly, the problem is in whatever sets the value of selectedGoal.Name.

Comment: I use `selectedGoal.Name` elsewhere in the page and it works fine, no misplaced quotes or anything.

Comment: Something is placing those quotes, and the code you have shown is not doing it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800473/how-to-concisely-create-optional-html-attributes-with-razor-view-engine/5490925#5490925

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your value attribute is missing its own quotes, so they are being automatically added before the space. Try moving `value` outside of the expression.

```
value="@(selectedGoal == null ? "" : selectedGoal.Name)"
```

Comment: Comes out like this: `value=""Goal" 2&quot;`.

Comment: @wohanley, I'm not sure where those extra sets of quotes would come from. Does `.Name` actually contain the quotes as part of the string?

Comment: It really, really shouldn't, but if this Razor is correct then maybe that's the only possibility. I'll triple-check.

Comment: There should be nowhere that quotes are added to `Name`, and it's working fine (that is, quote-free) in other places on the same page.

Comment: @wohanley, you're right try the updated answer. I think `@` is encoding the quotes again. My previous answer wrapped with `@Html.Raw` instead of just `@` seems to work, but this way is a little cleaner anyways.

Comment: That works. I'd rather not have the empty value attribute when `selectedGoal == null`, but good enough is good enough. Thanks.

Comment: @wohanley - the new version of Razor in MVC4 has a feature to remove empty attributes.  You would need to add additional logic to do it in MVC3.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
@(selectedGoal == null ? "" : "value=\"" + selectedGoal.Name + \")
```

Or you can try rendering them directly as an HTML  block, using my method on
[Html literal in Razor ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857204/html-literal-in-razor-ternary-expression/17223692#17223692)

Comment: It will escape the HTML encode the quotes, so this won't work. Did you just guess?